# Multiple Bower json files

Tags: bower

I have the bower.json file in my main app directory (of my node and angular apps).

Then in the `bower_components` directory there are in each respective component/module another bower.json file.

Why are they needed?

Answer (score 0):

Each bower dependency you import in your project is a complete module that you will depend on. Therefore this component must have a name, a version and may come with its own bower dependencies too, that's what the bower.json is for.

It's like a big tree of packages linked by dependencies where your application sits on top.

You can read the official [documentation](http://bower.io/docs/creating-packages/#bowerjson) to learn more on the bower.json file and see all the options available.